# Can you show that this function is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a fixed invertible matrix, ${\bf X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and a vector $c\in[0,1]^n$ (i.e each element of $c$ is between $0$ and $1$). I have numerical evidence that the following function is a convex function of $c$ in this specific range, no matter the value of ${\bf X}$:

\begin{equation}
f(c) = \sum_{ij=1}^n\frac{X_{ij}^2 + (X_{ij}^{-1})^2 - 2c_ic_jX_{ij}X_{ij}^{-1}}{1-c^2_i}
\end{equation}

where $X_{ij}^{-1}$ is the $ij$-th element of the inverse of ${\bf X}$.

Unfortunately I cannot prove it is convex, and I was looking for advice; how would you go about this? Can you prove it is convex?

I've tried looking at the Hessian and showing it is positive semi-definite, or just trying to show that $f(\lambda c + (1-\lambda)c') \leq \lambda f(c) + (1-\lambda)f(c')$, but no dice. Are there other classic techniques? Or am I being dumb and missing an obvious reason it either is or isn't convex?

Comment: Can you start by commenting on the convexity of ∑-cicj/(1-ci^2)?

Comment: By $X_{ij}^{-1}$ do you mean the reciprocal of the $ij$ element or the $ij$ element of the reciprocal?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will consider the convexity of the term you suggest Saketh.
By $X_{ij}^{-1}$ I mean the ij element of the matrix ${\bf X^{-1}}$, i.e. the inverse of the matrix ${\bf X}$

Comment: So, again numerically, it seems that $-\sum c_i c_j/(1-c_i^2)$ is concave, but I've failed to prove that (sorry! first time trying to do these things!) @SakethMalyala, (A) how would you recommend showing this thing? and (B) is the convexity of the original function then obvious from this discussion?